# Form submit not working for the React Food App

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am trying to build this React Food App using Edamam API. React App is fetching by default data which I set state to "Chicken" but when I submit value through form ,its not fetching data. I am using useEffect to render my page when form submitted.

State and useEffect

```
import React,{useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';
import Recipe from "./Recipe"

function App() {

  const APP_ID = "personalId";
  const APP_KEY = "personalKey";

  const [recipeData, setrecipeData] = useState([])

  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("Chicken");

  useEffect( () => {
    getRecipe();
  },[] )
```

Fetching API

```
  const getRecipe = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`)
    const data = await response.json();
    setrecipeData(data.hits)
    console.log(data.hits);
  }
```

Event Handling

```
  function handleChange(event){
    
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setSearch(event.target.value);
    
  }

  function handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    setQuery(search);
   
  }
```

Components

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Recipe App</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="search-form">
        <input className="search-bar" type='text' onChange={handleChange} value={search}/>
        <button className="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {recipeData.map( eachRecipe =>(
        <Recipe
          key = {eachRecipe.recipe.label}
          title = {eachRecipe.recipe.label}
          calorie = {eachRecipe.recipe.calories}
        /> )) 
        }

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably because your `useEffect` function isn't listening to the `query` state's chages.

Try adding your state `query` into the `useEffect`'s dependency array, like so:

```js
useEffect( () => {
    getRecipe();
  },[query])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `uesEffect`'s dependency array is empty, so it *only renders* on the very first render since that never changes. I think you meant to put `[query]` in it. Alternatively you could just call the `getRecipe()` directly in the `handleSubmit()`